# По какой формуле составляются последующие слагаемые ряда arccos ec x?

Tags: математика, ряды

Имеется ряд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы узнать по какой формуле составляются последующие слагаемые этого ряда.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не соответствует тематике сайта (программирование и сис.администрирование)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перепишите в таком виде:

```
1  1   1 3  1    1 3 5  1    1 3 5 7  1
- *-   -*- *-    -*-*- *-    -*-*-*- *-
2  3   2 4  5    2 4 6  7    2 4 6 8  9
```

Так закономерность становится очевидной, нет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только учтите, что `!!` — не факториал от факториала, а [двойной факториал](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB#%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB)...